# When did Stack Exchange implement HTTPS?

Tags: discussion, ssl, safari

This is new right?  I heard running sites over https was avoided because of issues with ads but now it looks like the entire network has it.

Connection doesn't run over https by default though, at least not on iOS safari.  You have to type in the url manually, anybody know why?

---

*EDIT

I guess this is somewhat of a duplicate but I checked the original thread and couldn't find anything anything about typing https manually into the url.  I'd still like to know if it's normal to have to do this or if stack exchange should be connecting automatically over https.

Comment: "When did Stack Exchange implement HTTPS?/This is new right?" Long time ago, so no. "You have to type in the url manually, anybody know why?" because it isn't supported. "I'd still like to know if it's normal to have to do this or if stack exchange should be connecting automatically over https." when have you seen a site to redirect you to https? When they actively prevent you from not using it.

Comment: @braiam im a bit new to all this so could you explain the difference between https being implemented and supported?  Also is there any reason why a site wouldn't want to have an https connection required if it's available?

Comment: HTTPS implementation exists, but SE does not guarantee it will work. As a matter of fact, it still doesn't work network side: click https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ and see what happens.

Comment: Normal Human Thank you